# Mushroom Identification: White mushroom growing on tree (South America)

Tags: species-identification, mycology

Near the place I live in I noticed a little white mushroom growing on a tree trunk (a dead palm tree). I was curious to identify it, but from the little I learned so far white mushrooms are the worst to identify. I’m on Brasil, near the tropics in an Atlantic Forest predominant area, and I haven’t yet found a field guide for my region (if anyone knows any, or a field guide from a region that grows similar mushrooms I’d love to hear suggestions).

Also, I'm very novice when it comes to mushroom identification (still learning the basics), so if I missed some important characteristic, or misinterpreted something that can be spotted in the pictures I'd love to hear it. The whole point of identifying this mushroom is learning.

Below are some characteristics I noticed and some pictures from the mushroom:

- Region: Brazil southeast coast, state of São Paulo, predominantly Atlantic forest
- Grows in very small colonies, but every fruiting body comes from an individual point (No Cespitose)
- Presence of Volva
- No presence of partial veil (No Annulus)
- Pileus Color: White with some brown spots
- Stipe Color: White
- Wasn’t able to get a spore print, but when it grew old (at least I think that's what happened) and shrunk it looked like the spores where brown as can be seen in the pictures
- Narrows gills? (The fruiting body is small, so maybe relatively speaking it isn't narrow)
- Fruiting body leaves white stain in wood
- Margins of the Pileus are cracked

There's a new colony growing, so I might be able to collect a sample once it grows big enough and gather more information, as a proper spore print, since my guess of the spores being brown might be a mistake (maybe those brown things in the dead mushroom are not spores).

---

### Pictures:

Older colony
[image: Older colony]

[image: Older colony]

Recent colony
[image: Recent colony]
[image: Recent colony]
[image: Recent colony]

Shrunk fruitbody
[image: Shrunk fruitbody]
[image: Shrunk fruitbody]

Comment: Does it have a hollow stem? stem and cap size? The gills are like a Marasmiellus, and it's larger. A image of the gills in daytime and perhaps a lengthwise cross section would be cool. What's the region? There are s many more species of tropical mushrooms.

Comment: @com.prehensible Not sure about the hollow stem (would have to wait the new colony to grow so I can get a sample). Cap was about 1.5-2cm in diameter on the bigger ones, stem also about 1.5-2cm long. I'll update the question with a more specific location: it's Brazil southeast coast, state of São Paulo, on an area that is predominantly atlantic forest. Can you indicate a good field guide for this region? By the way, I looked at some pictures of different Marasmiellus species and some do look very similar to the ones growing here!